# 5xx or 4xx error with “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present”

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, fetch-api

My browser is logging the following message in the devtools console:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.… The response had HTTP status code 503.

**Background**: I have two apps. One that is an Express Node application connected to a Mongo database. The other is a basic web application that makes `POST` requests to the Node application via the Fetch API to get data from Mongo.

**Issue**: Though I receive no `CORS` errors on my local machine, I am given the error below as soon as I deploy my basic web application to production. The web application that makes a `POST` request to the Node app and gives me this:

The `POST` request does seem to work and the data is saved into Mongo but this error is being marked as a "Critical Error" in Heroku and is quite annoying.

I realize that I could set the `no-cors` option in Fetch but I believe that it is required since I am making a request to a url that is different than the origin. Right?

**Express Node App Code**

In my `app.js` file I have set the correct headers to ensure that other applications can make requests from different origins

app.js

```
// Add headers so we can make API requests
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

routes/api/api.js

```
router.post('/users/:url/upload-csv/:csv_name', (req, res) => {
  let csv_name = req.params.csv_name;
  let csv_string = csv_name+req.body.csv_string;

  User.findOne({url: req.params.url})
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.csv_files.length === 0) {
        user.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      } else {
        let foundExistingCSV = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < user.csv_files.length; i++) {
          if (user.csv_files[i].includes(csv_name)) {
            foundExistingCSV  = true;
            user.csv_files[i] = csv_string;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!foundExistingCSV) user.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      }
      user.markModified('csv_files');
      user.save();

      res.status(204);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400);
    });
});
```

**Basic Web App Code**

`POST` request I am making

utils.js

```
utils.exportToMongo = functions(table, name) {
  var exportPlugin = table.getPlugin('exportFile');
  var csv_string   = exportPlugin.exportAsString('csv');

  // Upload the CSV string and its name to Users DB
  fetch(`${utils.fetchUserURL()}/upload-csv/${name}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({csv_string: csv_string}),
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    })
  }).then((res) => {
    return {};
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return {};
  });
}
```

How can I remove the `503` error? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try changing your CORS settings to match this: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Answer (score 6):

An HTTP `5xx` error indicates some failure on the server side. Or it can even indicate the server just isn’t responding at all — e.g., a case might be, your backend tries to proxy a request to a server on another port, but the server is not even be up and listening on the expected port.

Similarly, a `4xx` indicates some problem with the request prevented the server from handling it.

To confirm, you can try making the same request using curl, or Postman, or something, and see if you get a `2xx` success response for the request, rather than a `5xx` or `4xx`.

Regardless, if you see a `5xx` or `4xx` error on the client side, some message should get logged on the server side to indicate what failed and why. So to identify what triggered the `5xx`/`4xx` error, check server logs to find messages the server logged before it sent the error.

As far as CORS error messages go, it’s expected that in most cases for a `5xx` or `4xx` error, servers won’t add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to the response; instead the server most likely will only send that header for `2xx` and `3xx` (redirect) responses.

So if you get the cause of an `5xx`/`4xx` error solved such that you can get a success response, you may find your CORS config is already working fine and you’ve got nothing left to fix.

Comment: Ah looks like you may be right! I went through the Heroku logs and found that the description of the `503` error was `Request Timeout`. Any ideas as to how I should fix this or is that a separate question? Thanks again!

Comment: Not clear what the cause might be without some further clues but yeah it seems like that’s a different enough problem from what’s described in the existing question here that it merits posting a separate new question for it so you can get more specific attention to it and help for that—for example, by including `http-status-code-503` and `heroku` in the set of tags you give it

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue,  the server doesn't support cross origin request. The API developer should change Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * (means from any origin).sometimes jsonp request will bypass, if its not working, google chrome provides plugins to change origin
[plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)