# Why am I getting intermittent CORS errors from AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, get

I am making a call to 2 APIs (which are hosted on the same server) using  2 AJAX requests, but every few refreshes, I get hit with a

> Failed to load https://someapiurl: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
>   is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is 
>       therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I have the requests wrapped in a when-then, since the data from the APIs is being used to populate 2 DataTables.

```
$.when(
  $.ajax({
    url: oneurl,
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(csvs) {
      onedata = csvs;
      //do something   
    }
  }),
  $.ajax({
    url: twourl,
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(csvr) {
      twodata = csvr;
      //do something
    }
  })
).then(function() {
  tableone.rows.add(onedata).draw();
  tabletwo.rows.add(twodata).draw();
});
```

Why do I only sometimes get CORS errors? I've read that it may have something do to with the PREFLIGHT request made intermittently, but how can this be prevented?

Comment: Any differences in method or request headers between cases? Irregardless you should implement CORS for cross origin requests anyway

Comment: data type `plaintext/form-data` will not cause pre-flight requests however, using `application/json` will make browser first make preflight request before original request.

Comment: @AtulSharma `dataType` is only used internally to know what to expect from server

Comment: The API server is configured to allow for cross origin requests, which makes me think that it may be the timing of the AJAX requests which is causing the issue. The data response is of type JSON, but for some reason dataType:"text" still works.

Comment: Could be improper config of CORS such as not accounting for OPTIONS method, or a server side redirect. Not all requests will trigger preflight. The dataType or response content type are really irrelevant

Comment: @charlietfl Would you be able to provide an example of what that proper configuration would look like generically?

Comment: @charlietfl And I get that not all requests will trigger preflight, but why is it that in this case, the same exact requests sometimes trigger preflight?

Comment: Not sure but since that's not something you can control would look at what you can control which is fixing the back end issues. What language are you using in back end?

Comment: You’re not getting intermittent CORS errors. You’re getting intermittent 500 errors. The server you’re sending the request to is intermittently having an internal server error that makes it fail to respond as expected. That has nothing to do with the CORS configuration. You’d need to check the server logs on that server to see what messages it’s logging on the server side about what’s causing the internal server failure that results in the 500 response.

Comment: @sideshowbarker When I make a single AJAX request to any one of those endpoints, I do not ever get the 500 error, but when I make multiple AJAX requests (like in this example), I do. Could that also be a factor?

Comment: My case was that my application wasn't loadbalanced properly. My request receives data from two different servers pointed by the same url via loadbalancing. One of them had the data and the other did not. @sideshowbarker 's ans helped me find it. Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [5xx or 4xx error with “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356494/5xx-or-4xx-error-with-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)