# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing error, but it *is* in the response headers

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cors

and thank you. I've searched this for a while, but most CORS questions here seem to be about how to enable CORS or get around it. That's not my problem. My problem is that my app (React.js running on localhost) is giving me the CORS error in the title while the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is clearly in the response. See this screen shot of Postman and Firefox output:
[postman and firefox output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Jv2.png)

Edit: per @T.J. Crowder, I've copied the output below in text:

Firefox console output:

> GEThttps://#####.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/asset-accounts
> [HTTP/2 200 OK 212ms]
>
> XHROPTIONShttps://#####.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/asset-accounts/newVal
> [HTTP/2 200 OK 32ms]
>
> XHRPOSThttps://#####.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/asset-accounts/newVal
> [HTTP/2 400 Bad Request 39ms]
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://#####.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/asset-accounts/newVal. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Response headers in postman

> Date →Sun, 30 Aug 2020 12:52:35 GMT Content-Type →application/json
> Content-Length →2 Connection →keep-alive x-amzn-RequestId
> →72437f3b-4541-4c36-b425-dbccb9d75b9e Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
> x-amz-apigw-id →SFYbCHGXoAMF6eg= X-Amzn-Trace-Id
> →Root=1-5f4ba113-bdab0ab0557f0e505bc9cba4;Sampled=0

**Technical background**

First, I'm new to both AWS and React. Forgive if I've missed something noobish.

I've set up an AWS lambda (node.js 12) post method via AWS API Gateway. I've enabled CORS on the method. My back-end lambda sends the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in response.

```js
   const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: responseBody,
    };
    return response;
```

My front-end is a React.js app running on localhost:3000. I'm invoking the post as follows:

```js
try {
  const params = {
    "assetAccountId": 'newVal',
    "balance": 0,
    "householdId": "headerVal",
    "isOpen": true,
    "nickName": this.state.newassetAccount.assetAccountNickName,
    "rate": 0.043
  };
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'household-id': 'fcdfea8b-dbc9-475f-8508-27b64101ce6c',
  };
  await axios.post(`${config.api.invokeUrl}/asset-accounts/newVal`, params, headers);
  this.setState({
    assetAccounts: [...this.state.assetAccounts, this.state.newassetAccount]
  });
  this.setState({
    newassetAccount: {
      "assetAccountNickName": "",
      "id": ""
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(`An error has occurred: ${err}`);
}
```

It's worth noting that I've gotten the get method to work and, as you see in the image, Firefox calls an options request just before the post that works. I can't see anything different in the AWS API gateway between the get, post, and options CORS setup or response headers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: With CORS you have to [explicitly allow headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-access-control-allow-headers) as well. Doesn't fit the error message, but may be something to look at.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is in **both** responses? It has to be both in the `OPTIONS` response and also the `POST` response.

Comment: It would help people help you if you provided the information from the screenshot **as text** rather than just as a *picture* of text. (It would certainly have helped me.) Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Jv2.png shows that the response is a 400 Bad Request error. That’s the problem which needs to be fixed. It’s normal and expected that a 400 error — or any other error — won’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. So you probably want to figure out what’s causing that 400 Bad Request error. It means your frontend code isn’t formatting the request in a way the server expects. So check the server logs on that API server to see what messages it’s logging before it sends that 400 error.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - Doh! Of course. Even if there were a CORS problem, it would be a 200 response, it's "just" that the browser would prevent the JavaScript code seeing it. Good catch.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, that was it. I was adding my request headers in the wrong way. Sorry, the error message in firefox was not the error message I should have been looking at. How do I mark yours as the correct answer? it's just a comment, right?

Comment: @DanMcConkey Glad to hear you got it resolved. As far as the answer, I think it’s basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356752/441757. So I went ahead and marked it as such.