# .NET Core random CORS errors under load/spike test

Tags: .net, azure, http-status-code-403, iis-10, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to do spike tests on our .NET Core 5 Web APIs and I encountered a strange behavior where under sudden load, the API would fail with a CORS error on the client side even though CORS is enabled and configured correctly.

**The Requests:**

- 500 requests were sent at once
- Each request would open 2 to 3 database connections asynchronously
- All requests return `async Task<IActionResult>`
- I made sure no non-blocking code exist in the request

**The Error:**

The CORS error message displayed on the client side is:
`Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Error: MissingAllowOriginHeader`.

Here is the response header received from the server:

```
content-length: 58
content-type: text/html
date: Wed, 18 Aug 2021 05:00:10 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

**Code and Server Config:**

Here is my Startup code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

  var origins = new List<string> { };

  origins.Add("https://localhost:44347");
  origins.Add("http://localhost:63405");
  origins.Add("https://localhost:44311");

  // Production domains
  origins.Add("https://test.test.com/");

  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
    options => {
      options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en");
      options.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("ar")
      };
      options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
      options.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
      {
    return new ProviderCultureResult(HttpUtil.GetLang(context.Request));
      }));
    });

  services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicy, builder =>
      {
        builder.WithOrigins(origins.ToArray())
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
      });
  });

  services.Configure<FormOptions>(o => {
    o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
  });

  services.AddCronJob<LogoutInactiveCmsUsers>(c => {
     c.TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
     c.CronExpression = @"*/30 * * * *";
  });

  services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "");

  services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

  services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
  var localizeOptions = 
  app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("ContentRootPath", env.ContentRootPath);
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("WebRootPath", env.WebRootPath);

  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors(corsPolicy);

  if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-local-development");
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    app.UseHsts();
  }
            
  app.UseRequestLocalization(localizeOptions.Value);

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<RealTime>("/api/v1/realtime");
  });

  app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
  });
}
```

The server specs are:

- Hosted on Azure VM
- 16 GB RAM
- 4 virtual processors @2.6 GHz

**What I already tried:**

- Commented most of the config to a point where only use routing, use cors and use endpoint only remained. Still, the CORS error would show anyway.
- Made sure all requests are called asynchronously
- Made sure the server is only handling these requests exclusively
- Captured the logs and saw no errors when the spike requests are called
- Tried to allow all origins using:
  `app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowCredentials());`

**Closing remarks:**

Please note that we still didn't implement any rate limiting yet. This will be done later after we go live.
For now I want to know, shouldn't the server be able to handle such spikes normally? It is ok if the response is delayed for an extended time, but for it to fail completely with a CORS error is a bit strange.

Comment: When it’s under a sudden load and you get that CORS error, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it to you, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools to check it. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I just checked and I'm getting 403 errors on FireFox albeit less than those on Chrome.

Comment: So then the root error is that 403 error, right? The CORS error is just a side effect of that 403. About that, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356752/. So even if you weren’t getting that secondary CORS error, you’d still have a 403 error happening that you’d need to troubleshoot. The CORS configuration is not the cause of that 403. To figure out the cause of the 403, you want to look at the server logs of the API server, and see what messages the server is logging there prior to sending that 403 response.

Comment: Add to what sideshowbarker said, you can use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to trace the errors or logs when the api application running on IIS server. And if the api application is developed by yourself, you can also add some logs in the code and then use "Logging" module of IIS to check the logs for further investigation.